# Postgres select sum by months

Tags: postgresql, select

I have table evidence:

```
id      id_customer     id_service     amount       date 
1           1                1          50.0        2018-01-10
2           2                1          15.7        2018-01-18
3           3                2          14.9        2018-02-07
4           1                3          700.0       2018-02-28
5           2                1          250.0       2018-03-19
6           3                2          315.7       2018-03-08
7           1                1          100.0       2018-04-28
8           2                2          132.0       2018-04-26
```

I want to make SUM by month of year 2018 and have output like this:

```
  amount  month
    65.7     1
    714.9    2
    565.7    3
    232.0    4
```

This is my select which I want help with.

```
select sum(amount),extract(month from date) from evidence where extract(year from date)=2018 and amount>0 group by date;
```

Comment: `GROUP BY extract(month from date)` Otherwise you are grouping by the actual date, which gives you a group for each source record. You want to group by each month, not date.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS amount , date_trunc('month', date) as month
FROM evidence 
WHERE extract(year from date)=2018
GROUP BY month
```